# Get specific element out of "getRange" array

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to get an sepcific element out of the Spreadsheet array i created.

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var test = table.getRange('A1:D1').getValues()
    var test2 = test[1]
    Logger.log(test2)
}
```

Comment: Well? What's stopping you? You've already grabbed a specific element out of an array. Hint: what's the return value format for `Range#getValues`? What does it *semantically* return?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*According to the documentation on `getValues()`:*

> Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column.

#### What to fix:

If you want to get the value from cell `A1` in your example, you need to change:

```js
var test2 = test[1];
```

to:

```js
var test2 = test[0][0];
```

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - `Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)